# string manipulation in java, getting first characters

Tags: java, string

Lets say I have a string whose format is "name_surname". I mean there are 2 dynamic parts, and between them an underscore. I want to separate them and have in a variable the left part (name) and in another the right (surname).

Basically i want the reverse of this: `String temp=name+"_"+surname;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `split();`

```
String[] parts = temp.split("_");
String name = parts[0];
String surname = parts[1]; // <-- comment
```

Commented line will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if your name does not contain the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You should use split.

```
String fullName = "name_surname";
String[] components = fullName.split("_");
String firstName = components[0];
String lastName = components[1];
```

Comment: Do you mean `lastName = components[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use StringTokenizer

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "_");
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());
        }
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is now deprecated.

Comment: Oh I see. Well makes sense anyways it was not good for complex lookups